# Netcat server is not responding to SYN request from client

Tags: tcp, ip, tcpclient, ethernet, netcat

### Context

- Client configuration : STM32U585 with ENC28J60 ethernet controller and NetX TCP/IP stack.
- Server configuration : netcat sample server running on ubuntu (exact command : netcat -l -p 6001 -s 192.168.1.2 -v)
- Client and server are directly connected with ethernet cable(no router in between).
  No PPP configuration is done in NetX stack. Server MAC address as well as IP address are hard-coded in client.
- SYN packet is received in server machine. Verified through Wireshark
- Same server is able to establish connection with netcat client running on another linux machine.

Why SYN-ACK packet is not generated from server? Please refer the packet info and give some guidance. Thanks in Advance.

Details of SYN packet received in Wireshark(running in server) is attached below(Destination MAC address edited. It is same as the server hardware MAC address).

```html
   Frame 1: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits) on interface enx00e121212121, id 0
Interface id: 0 (enx00e121212121)
    Interface name: enx00e121212121
Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
Arrival Time: Mar  1, 2023 14:30:32.775293348 IST
[Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
Epoch Time: 1677661232.775293348 seconds
[Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
[Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
[Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
Frame Number: 1
Frame Length: 62 bytes (496 bits)
Capture Length: 62 bytes (496 bits)
[Frame is marked: False]
[Frame is ignored: False]
[Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp]
[Coloring Rule Name: TCP SYN/FIN]
[Coloring Rule String: tcp.flags & 0x02 || tcp.flags.fin == 1]
Ethernet II, Src: Coherent_8b:10:11 (00:1b:1c:8b:10:11), Dst: RealtekS_68:05:03 (00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX)
Destination: RealtekS_68:05:03 (00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX)
    Address: RealtekS_68:05:03 (00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX)
    .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
Source: Coherent_8b:10:11 (00:1b:1c:8b:10:11)
    Address: Coherent_8b:10:11 (00:1b:1c:8b:10:11)
    .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.13, Dst: 192.168.1.2
0100 .... = Version: 4
.... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
    .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
Total Length: 48
Identification: 0x0001 (1)
Flags: 0x00
    0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
    .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
    ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment Offset: 0
Time to Live: 128
Protocol: TCP (6)
Header Checksum: 0xb767 [validation disabled]
[Header checksum status: Unverified]
Source Address: 192.168.1.13
Destination Address: 192.168.1.2
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 6000, Dst Port: 6001, Seq: 0, Len: 0
Source Port: 6000
Destination Port: 6001
[Stream index: 0]
[Conversation completeness: Incomplete, SYN_SENT (1)]
[TCP Segment Len: 0]
Sequence Number: 0    (relative sequence number)
Sequence Number (raw): 4106063055
[Next Sequence Number: 1    (relative sequence number)]
Acknowledgment Number: 0
Acknowledgment number (raw): 0
0111 .... = Header Length: 28 bytes (7)
Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
    000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
    ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
    .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
    .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
    .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
    .... ...0 .... = Acknowledgment: Not set
    .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
    .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
    .... .... ..1. = Syn: Set
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): Connection establish request (SYN): server port 6001]
            [Connection establish request (SYN): server port 6001]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
    .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
    [TCP Flags: ··········S·]
Window: 512
[Calculated window size: 512]
Checksum: 0x5053 [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
Urgent Pointer: 0
Options: (8 bytes), Maximum segment size, No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), End of Option List (EOL)
    TCP Option - Maximum segment size: 1460 bytes
        Kind: Maximum Segment Size (2)
        Length: 4
        MSS Value: 1460
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
        Kind: No-Operation (1)
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
        Kind: No-Operation (1)
    TCP Option - No-Operation (NOP)
        Kind: No-Operation (1)
    TCP Option - End of Option List (EOL)
        Kind: End of Option List (0)
[Timestamps]
    [Time since first frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since previous frame in this TCP stream: 0.000000000 seconds]
```

Comment: Could it be a firewall on this Linux machine is blocking the traffic? Have you tried turning the firewall off?